# How can I access the stack of a suspended thread that hasn't started running yet?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to alter the stack of a newly created remote thread, but upon invoking CreateRemoteThread to create a thread in a suspended state, the stack has not been allocated.

I'm using GetThreadContext to get the address of ESP after creating the suspended thread, though if I look at this address in my disassembly window in the VS debugger, it has not been allocated. Also, writing to this address using WriteProcessMemory fails every time.

How can I edit the stack of a newly created but suspended remote thread?

Comment: Why do you want to edit the stack? Is there an easier way to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm try to call a function remotely, take a look at my previous qusetion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307968/how-do-you-call-a-function-in-another-address-space-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get thread handle, its stack is allocated, (as well as TIB structure).

MSVS debugger may show wrong information, so don't rely on it.
I'm not sure if thread context has correct values, maybe it's set later.

You should use `TIB` structure to get stack addresses, if it's really what you need.

If you just want to call function remotely before thread function invocation, you can use `QueueUserAPC` or `RtlRemoteCall`, both works when thread is created with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag.

Comment: Ugh, I should read on windows internals more - this API is amazing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're stating seems rather logical to me. Since you created the new thread as suspended there has not been a call to the thread function yet and therefore there is no stack yet.

Maybe you can start the thread normally and let the thread suspend itself as the first operation to be done.

Comment: there may or moy not be a stack ,but things get pushed onto it as part of a call to function (in this case the thread-function) and there is only a suspended call waiting (it is not called yet). So you can't edit something on the stack that isn't there.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this, which should work - hmm, well, I'll leave the question open for a while and see what other answers emerge. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I think I may end up using a mutex or some sort of synchronization object instead of suspending the thread - which makes a lot of more sense as its harder to and less predictable to work with the state of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you should already have access to the target thread's registers, so if you set its single-step flag and un-suspend it, one instruction will execute, then you'll get control back -- but to run even that single instruction, its stack should have been allocated. This should give roughly the same effect as @Edwin's answer, but without requiring you to modify the target thread.

Comment: If I understand Edwin correctly, I believe the thread-function is called from within the kernel, and so if I single-step my thread I will probably have EIP ending up somewhere in the kernel without the stack being setup. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Jeremy: at least if memory serves, yes, you're wrong. There is a fair amount of kernel-mode code involved, *but* it doesn't run as part of your thread. The single-step should execute one instruction of the code you've specified for your thread function -- the kernel code runs as a separate thread.

Comment: Hmm, this method is doable, but it just occurred to me that because this thread is remote, I would need to install an exception handler in the remote target, which is quite a bit of work compared to Edwin's solution. Please, correct me if I am wrong though - as I would like to use this solution if possible. Assuming we're both talking about the Trap Flag.